# Run executable (exe) program on client machine instead of on the server using ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, asp.net, activexobject

I have developed an executable program and deployed it on my local machine. Also, I have developed an ASP.NET Web application and deployed it on the server. The ASP.NET Web application can call the executable program on my local machine using ActiveXObject (Javascript), the program works as expected. But, I noticed that the executable program runs on the server instead of on the local machine.

Is it possible to run the executable program on the client machine instead of on the server?

Comment: No it is not possible at all

Answer (score 1):

Insted of active Have a look on it might help u......

```
using System.Diagnostics;

    //Get path of the system folder.
    string sysFolder =
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System);
    //Create a new ProcessStartInfo structure.
    ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    //Set the file name member. 
    pInfo.FileName = sysFolder + @"\eula.exe";
    //UseShellExecute is true by default. It is set here for illustration.
    pInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    Process p  = Process.Start(pInfo);
```

//or

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe")
```

or

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\nes\nes.exe");
```

or

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Server.MapPath("`/SanScan.exe"));
```